# How to understand the difference between transfer and function call using assembly call(g,a,v,in,insize,out,outsize)

Tags: assembly, transfer, calldata

I understand that if there is an external function call, it will use all 7 parameters of the `call(g,a,v,in,insize,out,outsize)`. However, I got a question I know low-level transfers like .transfer() will also use the instruction `call(g,a,v,in,insize,out,outsize)`, if wei > 0, I can treat it as transfers, does that make sense? Meanwhile, should there still be 7 parameters for the instruction `call`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CALL` can be used for multiple purposes: mainly function calls and variants of sending ethers: `transfer` `payable` and `call`.
To distinguish between function calls and ether transfer, the simplest way is to check if **the input data is blank** (the 4th item from the stack's top means input length so it's zero). If the `CALL` is sending ether it has zero input length. Otherwise, the length of the input [follows abi encoding](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html) (e.g. 4 bytes if calling function without argument)

I used the [ethervm.io](https://ethervm.io/) annotation for the above :

Opcode CALL

Stack : gas | addr | value | argsOffset | argsLength | retOffset | retLength

- Value > 0 is not an indicator of transfer because it can be a call to `payable` function in the external contract (when argsLength > 0).
- With `argsLength == 0`, to distinguished between different variants of sending ethers, you can look at the gas forwarded (the first item from the stack). If it's `0x8fc`, it's probably `transfer` or `send`. Otherwise it's direct call. Look at [this article from solidity docs for the differences between variants for sending ether](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/security-considerations.html#sending-and-receiving-ether)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: Does it answer your question?, if yes please mark it as the answer. Otherwise, you can further comment on what else do you expect from the answer.